# Detecting newest Excel file and convert to html

Tags: php, excel

can you please help with my project, i'm just newbie on PHP programming.

i had an excel reader php, it's working good, converting my excel file into PHP .

i want hopefully to detect the newest excel file in the folder then convert it into html using excel reader.

is that possible?

hope you can help me, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over a directory in PHP by using `dir` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php )and then use `filemtime` to check when the file was modified (http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php ).

As for converting to HTML - I assume that you have your Excel file loaded into PHP data structures (objects or arrays for example); if so, you can easily generate HTML using `echo` statements or - perhaps a bit more advanced - a teplating system.

Comment: thanks Pawel ;) it helps a lot